# How to correct VS Code terminal pointing to wrong folder C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0?

Tags: reactjs, powershell, visual-studio-code

I try to open a *React* project path in terminal window using VS Code's **Open in Integrated Terminal** (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+`</kbd>), but it sets `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` as current directory and not the project directory.

It doesn't behave like that for other projects (folders & paths).
This happened after I moved the files to another folder on my PC.

[Screen shot of VS Code context menu with menu item Open in Integrated Terminal and the TERMINAL window with Windows PowerShell output and the path set as current directory.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewXAC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is return to special characters in file name.
characters like [ , ] made this error on VS code. git bash and CMD run well with them but vs code not.im not certain this is a bug or not

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).